# Multiple colors in JavaFX Textarea

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

How would I change the color of different text in a textarea in JavaFX? I've been doing some research, and I can only find solutions for Java Swing, not JavaFX.

To describe my situation, I'm trying to highlight different keywords in code, like a IDE. Basically, like this:

[image: Color coded text]

In the above image, certain words are different colors.(`.list` is red, `span` is blue, etc.)

Does anyone know how to apply this effect to a JavaFX Textarea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) lets you to assign different styles to different ranges of text. You will have to parse the CSS yourself, though. See the [demo of highlighting Java keywords](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX#automatic-highlighting-of-java-keywords)

Comment: How would I put the library in my project so i can use it? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is described [here](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX#use-richtextfx-in-your-project). There are two options: 1) use Maven, Gradle or Sbt to download the dependencies automatically; or 2) download the JAR file and place it somewhere on your classpath.