# How can I get Textflow editable in Javafx 8?

Tags: javafx-8

I have an Editor with a `TextArea` which is editable but it is not possible to dye the keywords in another Color.

So I want to Change the `textarea` into a `Textfllow` which is editable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple colors in JavaFX Textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388378/multiple-colors-in-javafx-textarea)

Comment: What have you done already? Show us your effort that you put into trying to solve your problem. Otherwise you're just asking us to write code for you.